# Am I required to re-attach neighbours gate to my fence post?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales

I’ve had my my fence replaced including new posts, which I’m 100% sure is my my fence, post, and boundary.

Previously the neighbour’s gate was directly attached to my fence post, I’ve allowed it to be re-attached to the new post but was I legally required to do so?

Could I have simply removed the gate and left it on their side of the boundary?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on who is [responsible](https://www.inbrief.co.uk/neighbour-disputes/ownership-of-fences/) for the boundary.

If they are responsible then you have done them a kindness by building a fence for them. Naturally, as its their fence they can do what they like with it.

If you are jointly responsible then they can also do what they like with it providing they don't harm its functionality.

If you are responsible, then they need your permission, which you have given.